# Supervised master students not following instructions: how common and how to deal with them?

Tags: phd, postdocs, supervision

I started as a postdoc at the end of last year, and my background is computer science if this helps. My current PI asked me to supervise two students, both went really bad (details below).

**Student 1**

This is a research-based master student (not sure if this is unique in UK universities), who needed to focus on a single research project for approx. 8 months (including writing up). This student only did what he had been told to without thinking about why and what to do next. Even if he was given rather clear instruction, he did not follow all of them. His data collection and experiments were also rather messed up with lots of errors. Even the PI herself found this student very difficult to deal with, so initially I believed it was not my fault that he did not make much progress.

**Student 2**

This is a MSc student who needed to do a mini project, which lasted approx. 1.5 months (including writing up). The problem here is this student did not follow my advice at all. The student refused to use the algorithms suggested in the beginning, but chose to compare a few algorithms with the given dataset. I pointed out to compare performances, a single dataset was not enough. But she said she had no time to do more experiments. I also explained the importance of model selection several times and send her several references on this topic, spending almost two weeks persuading her to do some model selection. But in the end, I found her code was completely wrong. I pointed this out and shared an online example, what she needed to do was just to copy and paste the code and change the parameters. She copied the example, but in an incorrect way, and she said she had no time to do this again. Maybe I am too critical, but re-running the experiments really wouldn't take more than one/two hours.

**Question**

My bad experience with these two students makes me to re-think whether I am indeed the problematic person. From my experience during PhD, I thought students themselves needed to make sure their implementation is correct. But both students had errors in their code and I won't be able to discover them without looking at their code carefully. This also seems an expectation from my PI (to check their code line by line), which was never required by my PhD supervisors. Additionally, my current PI did not help much on supervising both students.

I wonder if this is a common issue for PhD/postdocs that when supervising students, 1) the students usually don't follow the advice; 2) PhD/postdocs are responsible to check their code and 3) supervisors contribute very little.

Comment: The general question about thesis supervision is rather broad and does not match the specific issue in your situation very well. I slightly modified your question to highlight the specific issue.

Comment: If you supervise them, you were probably one of the better students in your time. You cannot assume that everyone is as motivated as you. You have to adapt to the students' level of motivation and skill.

Comment: Are you communicating your concerns with the students or just allowing them to accrue to critical mass? Transparency, honesty, and authenticity are vital to all relationships whenever an issue arises. It may be uncomfortable, but if you whole heartedly believe the students are becoming their own worst problem, then you should discuss this with them.

Comment: I might write a more extensive answer, but are you sure that the students understand the demands and required effort of a dissertation? Do they realise how rigorous, independent and challenging it is, or do they think it is a long coursework where you will follow them the same way they can rely on module material? Also consider that even if you have explained it to them, thay might still not understand, or refuse to do so. The point by @CaptainEmacs is also important.

Comment: I've had very few students who want to do things their way rather then my way. Doing things their own way is fine if they get good results. But if they're messing things up, then I'd insist on changes.  (This is in the context of faculty supervising  students; I didn't supervise anyone while I was a student myself.)

Comment: I think this is a usual trap to fall in, you assume motivation and dedication, maybe from your own personal experience. However, not all students are necessarily motivated about and interested in their studies and very often it is just about getting a decent grade with a minimum of effort. So try to support especially motivated individuals and manage your expectations and demands in other cases.

Comment: I'm going to close this, as I suspect it varies too widely for us to be able to give a good answer. The situation at a competitive, top school is doubtless very different than the situation at a less prestigious school where there is a strong expectation that students will pass. And here there are added unknowns about the professor's expectations.